# How to pass mean() as input parameter to another function in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6, pandas-groupby

I have data which I need to group either by mean or median. I want to write a function for this. This is what I tried so far

```
def clean(data, met = np.mean):
    data_grouped = data.groupby(['zipcode','neighbourhood'], as_index=False).met()[['zipcode', 'neighbourhood','revenue']]
return data_grouped
```

This throws an error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'met'
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Have you considered `met(data.groupby(['zipcode','neighbourhood'], as_index=False))[['zipcode', 'neighbourhood','revenue']]`?

Comment: `groupby().met()` means you are treating `met` as a method.  Methods are attributes, hence the error.  `np.mean` and `np.median` are numpy functions, not methods of the `groupby` object.

Comment: You could pass the method name as a string `met='mean'` and  then use `operator.methodcaller(met, <args>)(<object>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

you can change `met` to `median` at the end (rather than `mean`, but for me it only worked when I specified the actual `groupby` methods (rather than use `numpy`'s).

Also, notice that `met` comes at the beginning rather than the end of the expression

```
def clean(data, met = pandas.core.groupby.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.mean):
    return met(data.groupby(['zipcode','neighbourhood'], as_index=False)['zipcode', 'neighbourhood','revenue'])
```

It worked for me on a different dataset